# Did JFK have an affair with Marilyn Monroe?

Tags: sexuality, jfk

There are a [variety of rumors](https://youtu.be/v9nl2vKBp-U?t=29s) on this topic, many with vague sourcing. That they [had an affair](https://www.quora.com/John-F-Kennedy-What-evidence-is-there-that-JFK-and-Marilyn-Monroe-had-an-affair), that confidants on both sides have confirmed it, that it influenced Monroe's infamous "Happy Birthday, Mr. President", and then the typical [Daily Mail stuff](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-1209783/Madness-Marilyn-Monroe-The-affair-JFK-drug-crazed-paranoia.html), including [a supposed sex tape of JFK, RFK, and Monroe](http://www.nydailynews.com/entertainment/gossip/jfk-rfk-marilyn-monroe-three-way-sex-tape-sale-article-1.1707159).

What was the nature of their affair, and what parts are beyond reliable confirmation?

Comment: [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marilyn_Monroe) `they sometimes had casual sexual encounters, there is no evidence that their relationship was serious`, quoting 3 books.

Comment: Considering at first glace my answer was 'duh', there's not really a whole lot to go on to prove they had an affair.  Although it's probably impossible to prove either way, considering people have been trying to figure it out for 60 years now